# What does "unhashable type: 'list'" error mean?

Tags: python

```
//database Postgresql

logging_level_ENUM = ['critical', 'error', 'warning', 'info', 'debug']

loglevel = db.Column(postgresql.ENUM(logging_level_ENUM, 
                     name='log_level_to_ENUM'), 
                     default=logging_level_ENUM[3])
//python module

if i in logging_level_ENUM:
    print i
```

This gives me an error "unhashable type: 'list'". What does that mean and how can I fix that?

Comment: What is giving that error, be more specific to your question... please read how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also check [How to Ask Good Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you increase your chances to get feedback and useful answers.

Comment: Fixed code indent and corrected English grammar.

Answer (score 0):

Python lists are not hashable because they are mutable.  You need to use a hashable collection instead, like a tuple.

`logging_level_ENUM = ('critical', 'error', 'warning', 'info', 'debug')`

Answer (score 0):

Basically, when you create a dictionnary in python (which is most probably happening in your call to the ENUM function), the keys need to be hashable, which often means the collection needs to be immutable (which means they should not be able to be modified).

Here is a more detailed explanation of why this is the case : https://wiki.python.org/moin/DictionaryKeys

As the previous answer states, you probably need to use a hashable collection such as a tuple to solve the problem in your example code.